# MSBuild The import project <x> was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm getting an error that "The import project '[file path here]' was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

However, I can confirm that [file path here] is correct and does represent an accurate file that does exist on the disk. Running as administrator does not fix the problem, restarting VS does not fix the problem, and expanding the environmental variables that create the path do not fix the problem.

Edit: The file is on a local disk, not a share, and my account is a local administrator, so there are no possible permissions issues here (especially since running as admin didn't resolve the issue)

Edit2: This only happens with isolated files and is not systemic through all imported projects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can it be an issue with bitness? e.g. if your proj files are in `System32` then on 64 bit machines 32 bit version of msbuild would look for them in `SysWOW64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that since there was a conditional on the Identifier i was using allowing others to override it, a different file was overriding it with the same identifier but with a space, removing the conditional fixed the problem.

Key takeaway here, make sure you know who and what are setting your variables.

Comment: `/v:diag` will explain what conditions were evaluated on each task.  (I'm not sure if it reports on includes too)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals tools to check what paths are actually accessed during the build. This should give you the idea of what is missing. Make sure to filter only for required process and from you description it seems you need only to check file system access. Otherwise you will get a lot of events and it will be much harder to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: It appears to be inserting a space into the filename for no good reason.
I set a indentifier <ID>SomeFile</ID> and reference it later <ImportName>$(ID)somemoreinfo</ImportName> and somehow in the middle of $(ID) there is a space.